Why am I missing older Time Machine backups after a recent backup was created?
I am looking for some help recovering a Time Machine backup. I have an older iMac running macOS 10.6.8 connected to an external Apple drive. Back in 2018 the original hard drive in the iMac failed. I was able to successfully install a new hard drive and load the OS. At the time I tried recovering a Time Machine backup of the whole computer but it would not overwrite the files on the new drive.
At the time I thought the issue was because I named the replacement hard drive a different name. I ended up just leaving it since it wasn’t a primary computer.
Recently I wanted to recover my files and old pictures so I revisited. I found I could connect to Time Machine and see all of the old back ups going back to like 2010. I tried highlighting the drive name in the Time Machine backup and recovering but it encountered a message saying it could not replace the system folder.
After doing some searches online I tried creating a second admin user and recovering Time Machine with the same result.
Next I thought I would try making a new Time Machine backup to see if that made any difference. After it was complete I could no longer see all of the original backups through Time Machine or the Finder.
I am guessing the new backup changed permissions or the name of the backups and I can no longer see them? My external drive was only at about 25% of capacity so Time Machine shouldn’t have overwritten the older files.
How can I recover my old pictures?

Are you sure that Time Machine didn’t decide it needed to delete the old backups to make space for a new interval? Check the state of warn me when Time Machine deletes backups as it’s easy to miss and you get that alert after the first deletion has finished.

Also, someone is going to need to sit with you and ask 20 questions to get to the nub of things. “What is an Apple drive”, what exactly is the name of each computer, what OS is running now and what was the version in the past you hope to recover, can we verify things enough to have a concrete timeline of what we know from existing logs on the backup destination and on the computer(s) to determine what happened in the past…

I just verified “notify after old backups are deleted” is enabled.  I didn’t receive any notifications during the recent backup process.

Sadly, if you missed that notification one time, it’s plausible it found one or more very large intervals to delete, did the delete and you will need expensive or time consuming recovery efforts. I would find someone you can sit with to sort out a bunch of details before you decide to isolate the drive (no more writing data to in) and spend time and possibly money to find deleted files.

Thank you for the feedback.  I am willing to walk through it with someone.  Any recommendations on who could help support me with this?  With some guidance I can navigate through checking some things.

Since this is a worldwide resource, start with Apple or https://consultants.apple.com/us/ if you don’t know anyone in your community. Sometimes pizza party for an eager tech minded intern or relative is an inexpensive way to get someone to work on the basics for you. It really depends how precious these memories are if you “hire” an amateur and they make a mistake. To me, it’s not even clear you can’t browse those backups and locate pictures. Again, you may have done some basic troubleshooting, but this site isn’t a good place to outsource this kind of management or labor.

Hi “bmike”, I found some additional information in the system logs.  See below.  This occurred when I turned Time Machine on and it made a new backup.
Dec 16 20:40:00 JEFF-BROWNs-iMac com.apple.backupd[239]: Deleted backup image: /Volumes/Data-1/Jeff Brown’s Computer_2019-01-13-211731.sparsebundle. 1856.0 GB available on host volume.
Dec 16 20:40:00 JEFF-BROWNs-iMac com.apple.backupd[239]: Creating disk image /Volumes/Data-1/JEFF BROWN’s iMac.sparsebundle

As long as the files aren’t overwritten, a data recovery service should be able to quote you standard rates to recover the files. Sparse bundles are challenging to piece together in my experience so that’s unfortunate. Off the shelf tools work better on standard file systems, but maybe there’s better options than data rescue or pro companies.
